# Concatenate variables containing multiple lines in bash

Tags: bash, merge, echo

Given `echo "$varA"`:

```
Astringline1
Astringline2
Astringline3
```

and `echo "$varB"`:

```
Bstringline1
Bstringline2
Bstringline3
```

I would like to obtain:

```
Astringline1,Bstringline1
Astringline2,Bstringline2
Astringline3,Bstringline3
```

`echo "$varA,$varB"` produces:

```
Astringline1
Astringline2
Astringline3,Bstringline1
Bstringline2
Bstringline3
```

Comment: Are you sure `echo $varA` (with no quotes) produces what you're showing?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thanks for pointing that out, I have made the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `paste` command:

```
varA=$'Astringline1\nAstringline2\nAstringline3'
varB=$'Bstringline1\nBstringline2\nBstringline3'
paste -d, <(echo "$varA") <(echo "$varB")
```

#### output

```
Astringline1,Bstringline1
Astringline2,Bstringline2
Astringline3,Bstringline3
```

Comment: Nice! Explanations: The `<()` creates a subshell (to run `echo`) then expands to the file name `/dev/fd/xx` where the subshell is redirected out. Thus here two temp files are created, containing expected values, then the file names are given to `paste` as arguments.

Comment: The entry in `/dev/fd` may refer to a pipe, rather than an actual file. It depends on how `bash` implements process substitution on any given platform.